# dismiss more than one View Controllers to return to the root ViewController in ios13

Tags: ios, swift

I have three view controllers written programmatically, the first VC is **Sign in** but if the user forgets the password this will led him to another two view controllers I need to return to the **sign in** VC directly form the third VC after the user finish the specific procedures.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, I get a reference from the third VC and I tried this `thirdVC.dismiss(animated: true)`

Comment: Are your view controllers embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: no, it is not embedded in a navigation controller @AlanS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do like this

```
self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

since are both vc to dissmiss it will return to login vc.
every presented viewController has a property called 
PD: presentingViewController, is hold as reference to the viewController that is responsable for present it, so 2dn VC has a reference to 1st VC as presentpingviewcontroller, but also 3er VC have a reference to 2dn vc that has a reference to 1st VC so you call the above method chaining two presenting and ending in first VC, so you could present as many VC as you want as long as you know how many have been presented you could return to what ever you want.

Comment: it is works thanks, but I can not understand how this happened

Answer (score 0):

You can use navigation controller, push your view controllers to navigation like

```
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController: vc, animated: true)
```

and when you need to close all controllers use

```
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```